# Using a rolling window in time series regression

Tags: regression, time-series, descriptive-statistics

I am learning about regression. I have done some cross sectional regressions which are fine. I recently did a simple time series regression. So I have a y & x vectors each containing 1000 observations.

I did a simple ols regression in excel which I thought was fine. However my online tutor e-mailed me after I sent the results asking what rolling window I was using? I don't seem to follow. I have e-mailed back but received an out of office reply and I'm keen to understand what he meant.

Is it simply rather than using all 1000 observations that I should use the first 50 observations (so 1:49) for a regression then do another regression using obs (2:50)?

My understanding was that as long as the data in my vectors is ordered correctly (in my case my date) then the regression should be done in the same way as a cross sectional regression - am I wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Performing a rolling regression (a regression with a rolling time window) simply means, that you conduct regressions over and over again, with subsamples of your original full sample.

- For example you could perform the regressions using windows with a size of 50 each,
  i.e. from 1:50, then from 51:100 etc.
- Another approach would be to apply overlapping windows with a size of
  50 each. So for example using 1:50, then 41:90 etc. (cutting off the last 10 elements in each succeeding subsample regression).

As a result you will receive a time series of your regression coefficients, which you can then analyze.

Which approach to follow depends a lot on your context and what your research is aiming for.

Comment: EDC provides a fine answer. I would usually align the window to a seasonal boundary, so each window would be equally affected by any seasonality.  So, If I had weekly data, I might use 1-52, 14-65, 27-78, etc for overlapping windows.